# Modifying Relation into BCNF

Tags: rdbms, database-normalization, bcnf

I am learning DBMS and normalization and I have come across the following exercise. For the following problem:

```
Consider the relation R(b,e,s,t,r,o,n,g) with functional dependencies

         b,s -> e,r,o,n
         b -> t
         b -> g
         n -> b  
         o -> r

     (a) identify candidate keys

     (b) identify prime attributes

     (c) state the highest normal form of this table
```

I think that (a) would be {b, s} since they identify all attributes without redundancy.

(b) would also be {b, s} since they compose the candidate keys of (a).

(c) would be 1-NF for several reasons. It does not satisfy 2-NF since there are partial-dependencies n -> b. The aforementioned functional dependency only depends on b and not s, hence partial-dependency. It does not satisfy 3-NF since o -> r indicates that a non prime attribute depends on another non-prime attribute. BCNF is not satisfied since 3-NF is not satisfied.

Lastly, if I were to modify the table until it is in BCNF, would splitting the relation R into:

```
R1(b, e, s, r, o, n) with b, s -> e, r, o, n
```

and

```
R2(b, t, g) with b -> t and b -> g
```

while eliminating the n -> b and o -> r satisfy BCNF?

I am most confused on the last part regarding satisfying BCNF. I would greatly appreciate any help/thoughts on all steps!

Comment: The answers to (a) and (b) look right; the answer to (c) is wrong.  There's a transitive dependency b ⟶ o ⟶ r which prevents R1 being in BCNF.  The {b, s} ⟶ n and n ⟶ b pair also mean R1 is not in BCNF.  That portion is in 3NF, IIRC, but not BCNF.  You can't just throw away FDs.  You have to preserve them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema has two candidate keys: `{b, s}` and `{n, s}`. You can verify that both are keys be computing the closures of the two sets of attributes.

So the prime attributes are `b`, `s`, and `n`.

You are correct in saying that the relation is not in 2NF, neither in 3NF.

Your proposed decomposition does not produces subschemas in BCNF, since in R1 the dependency `o → r` still holds, and `o` is not a superkey of R1.

The “classical” decomposition algorithm for BCNF produces the following normalized schema:

```
R1(b g t)
R2(o r)
R3(b n)
R4(e n o s)
```

but the dependencies

```
b s → e
b s → n
b s → o
b s → r
```

are not preserved in the decomposition.

A decomposition in 3NF that preserves data and dependencies is the following:

```
R1(b e n o s) 
R2(b g t)    
R3(o r)
```

In this decomposition, R2 and R3 are also in BCNF, while the dependency `n → b` in R1 violates the BCNF.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If n -> b in R1 violates BCNF, doesn't that imply that this relation (R1,R2,R3) does not satisfy BCNF?

Comment: Yes. As I said, the decomposition is in Third Normal Form, not in BCNF. There cases in which a BCNF cannot be found without losing dependencies.